# Exporting div and css styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, dns, subdomain

I remember a while back about a javascript file that would export only the html div and relevant css styles to html and css files (not images or pdf). I would like that, or a way to include div `nav`in another document on a different subdomain: div `nav`on www.example.com onto subdomain.example.com. Any ideas?

Comment: Export what to where? Can you clarify what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Well i want styles.css with all the styles that are relevant, and nav.html with the div and relevant <head> variables (css, javascript etc.).

Comment: But want them where? In what context?

Comment: my site http://www.autisticaussies.com has a navbar. I want to put that navbar onto the subdomain bans and stats.

Comment: give an example of page A, and exactly what parts of it you want to move to page B, and clarify if the page B is already loaded, what it contains, or your creating it at the same time, there are millions of possibilities right now, be more specific

Comment: I want to put the div "nav"on www.autisticaussies.com onto the top of bans.autisticaussies.com and stats.autisticaussies.com

Comment: to what I understand you don't want to copy-paste the nav, as updating it would mean you need to update all instances in all pages, so you want a .js file to be executed that creates your nav `div`? then in any page where the .js is loaded the nav will be created? if this is the case please tell me

Comment: i will give u a picture of what i want

Comment: [link]www.mccarthyp64.com/screenie.png[/link] except bans is active and without the forum stuff (I can do that)